# I can not return Data in ajax

Tags: ajax, laravel

I can not get the response from the  controller with Ajax,what should I do?:

```
$("document").ready(function(){
    $("#send").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var question = $("input[name=question]").val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url : "/Admin/question/store?token={{$t}}",
            data : {'question':question},
            success : function(data){
                alert(data);
               console.log(data);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

and in the  controller I just want to return a string for testing:

```
public function store(Request $request)
          {
            return "success";
          }
```

Comment: To give you a great answer, it might help us if you have a glance at [ask] if you haven't already. It might be also useful if you could provide a [mcve].

Comment: Things to do to test:
1) check in your browser developer tools under network, filter by XHR and see the request being sent, together with any errors or response code

2) add a `dd()` in the constructor of the controller to ensure it is being called

Comment: As @MehrdadDastgir said, first try and check the same post but using a regular post, and verify it works. Then you can build upon it more complex things like ajax calls.

Comment: add pram dataType in ajax

Comment: are you sending any sensitive data ??

Comment: @AbdullaNilam no

Comment: token or _token  api_token  ?

Comment: @amini.swallow can you please show us your route as well?

Comment: @MehrdadDastgir Route::group(['namespace'=>'Admin','prefix'=>'Admin'],function(){ $this->post('/question/store','QuestionController@store')}     It worked without ajax with this route

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it,

First problem was URL,I changed it to:

```
  {!! route('store') !!}
```

And did not know to write my route in api!!!! instead of web

Answer (score 0):

For you to get the response in AJAX you must print the data, is it being print after the return? if not, try :

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    echo "success";
}
```